# Make bibtex output doi and url if applicable

Tags: bibtex, doi, url

I am using bibtex to format/generate a list of references, which are then processed further by another application to be included on web-pages.

Thus, I get output in the .bbl file of the form

```
\bibitem[FdBRT54]{FrameRobinsonThrall}
J.S. Frame, G.~de~B.~Robinson, and R.M. Thrall.
\newblock The hook graphs of the symmetric group.
\newblock {\em Canad. J. Math.}, 6:316--325, 1954.
```

This is great, but I would like to have the following (if present) extra blocks:

```
\newblock DOI: thedoi
\newblock URL: theurl
```

I have tried editing the `alpha` style file for formatting, but I never managed to produce this. I tried to fiddle around with `biber`, but it does not produce a nice .bbl file that I can extract the "formatted" references from.

EDIT: I use the alpha style, but editing that file would be fine, and use a custom style .bst file. I just don't know how to modify it.
Also, natbib seems nice,

Comment: There are plenty of `.bst` files that output DOI and URL fields.  Just use one of those.  Most `natbib` compatible styles will do it.

Comment: Please confirm that you use the `alpha` bibliography style. Are you amenable to using some other style? Please also indicate which citation management package (if any) you load.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found an answer:
Download [this .bst file](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/biblio/bibtex/contrib/urlbst/alphaurl.bst), do not use natbib,
and use the hyperref package.